# Start Date end date calculation based on date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to calculate StartDate and EndDate based on a date column from a table.
Below is the source table looks like

Scenario 1

| ID | SERIAL_NUMBER | STATUS | READ_DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 15-12-2021 |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 16-12-2021 |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 17-12-2021 |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 18-12-2021 |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 19-12-2021 |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 20-12-2021 |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 21-12-2021 |

I want to calculate start_date and end_date based on READ_DT, for a ID and SERIAL_NUMBER if all READ_DT are available then the output should be as below

| ID | SERIAL_NUMBER | STATUS | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 15-12-2021 | 21-12-2021 |

Scenario 2

| ID | SERIAL_NUMBER | STATUS | READ_DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 15-12-2021 |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 16-12-2021 |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 17-12-2021 |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 19-12-2021 |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 20-12-2021 |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 21-12-2021 |

If there is any gap present in between READ_DT then expected output should be in two transactions as below.

| ID | SERIAL_NUMBER | STATUS | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 15-12-2021 | 17-12-2021 |
| 123456789 | 42007 | D | 19-12-2021 | 21-12-2021 |

Comment: please also include your best attempt query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little sequential temporal math makes short work of these things.

```
--===== This will work for either scenario
   WITH cteDTgrp AS
(--==== Subtract an increasing number of days from each date to create the date groups.
 SELECT *
        ,DT_Grp = DATEADD(dd,-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,SERIAL_NUMBER,STATUS ORDER BY READ_DT),READ_DT)
   FROM dbo.YourTableNameHere
)--==== Then the grouping to get the start and end dates is trivial.
 SELECT ID,SERIAL_NUMBER,STATUS
        ,Start_Date = MIN(READ_DT)
        ,End_Date   = MAX(READ_DT)
   FROM cteDTgrp
  GROUP BY ID,SERIAL_NUMBER,STATUS,DT_Grp --<----This is the key!
  ORDER BY ID,SERIAL_NUMBER,STATUS,Start_Date
;
```

Note that this will only work if the READ_DT is unique for each group of ID,SERIAL_NUMBER,STATUS.

Comment: V elegant Jeff.  Merry Christmas!

Comment: @wBob -  Thank you for the feedback and Merry Christmas to you and yours.  Heh... and I wish everyone a better coming year than the last 2.

Comment: Thanks jeff, its working

Answer (score 0):

For scenario 1 you can direct use aggregate min and max functions group by remaining columns.

```
select ID,SERIAL_NUMBER, STATUS, convert(varchar, min(READ_DT), 105) as Start_Date, convert(varchar, max(READ_DT), 105) as End_Date 
from tb1
group by ID,SERIAL_NUMBER, STATUS
```

[image]

For Scenario 2, I used the LAG function to get the difference of date of the current row compared to the previous row and performed aggregation after that.

This code worked for scenarios 1 & 2 data.

Code:

```
   drop table if exists #t1 
  --stores diff_days and missing date from sequence
   SELECT READ_DT,
     case when DATEDIFF(day, LAG(READ_DT) OVER (ORDER BY READ_DT), READ_DT ) is NULL then 1 
     else DATEDIFF(day, LAG(READ_DT) OVER (ORDER BY READ_DT), READ_DT )
     end AS diff_day
    ,case when DATEDIFF(day, LAG(READ_DT) OVER (ORDER BY READ_DT), READ_DT ) >1 then DATEADD(day, -1, READ_DT)
     end as diff_read_dt
    into #t1
    from tb2

   --update diff_day column where date greater that missing date to aggregate on the result set
   update #t1
   set diff_day = diff_day+1
   where convert(date,READ_DT) > (select dateadd(day,1,convert(date,diff_read_dt)) from #t1 where diff_read_dt is not null)

  --get the required results using min and max

   select a.ID, a.SERIAL_NUMBER, a.STATUS, convert(varchar, min(a.READ_DT), 105) as Start_Date, convert(varchar, max(a.READ_DT), 105) as End_Date 
   from tb2 a
   inner join #t1 b on convert(date,a.READ_DT) = convert(date,b.READ_DT)
   group by a.ID, a.SERIAL_NUMBER, a.STATUS, b.diff_day
```

[image]

Comment: If the answer was helpful, You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.).